# JasperReports Server does not execute a query that iReport does

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports 4.7*, *iReport 4.7.1* and *PostgreSQL 8.4* as database backend.

While doing a report with a query similar to

```sql
(select * from table1)
union
(select * from table1)
```

I found that *iReport does* the report but when I upload the report to the *JasperReport Server* I get `An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (6632)`

I rewrote the query to

```sql
select *
from (
(select * from table1)
union
(select * from table1)
) t
```

And it works well with both *iReport* and *JasperReports*.

So, the question is, Am I missing something or Do I need to configure what?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change the UNION in your original query to UNION ALL?

Comment: Of course, the result changes on both queries because of the duplicate tuples, but the problem persist. The first query does not run on JasperReports.

Comment: Is the Postgres database your repository, or your data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of the "new" (since version 4.5) security features. SQL queries should start with a select when executed on the server. (your query starts with a "(")
try to disable the security check, FOR TESTING:

```
security.validation.sql.on=false
```

in:

```
webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security-config.properties
```

Comment: Thanks @robin.koch.

You right, it is because of the validation security feature.